# Loop template and event

Tags: meteor

My problem might be easy to solve, I have not been succesfull so far...

I try to create a list of articles, only with a name.

---

Article 1

[Button Show more]

---

Article 2

[Button Show more]

---

Article 3

[Button Show more]

---

...

```
The code looks like this :

{{#each article in articleSet}

<button value= {{ article.name }} </button>

// I want to load a template here of the article, when the button is clicked

{{ if condition = true}}
     {{ > getArticle article=this.article }}
{{/if}}

{{/each}}
```

My problem : I want only the clicked button to render the article under him, not all. How can I make a logical connexion between which button has been clicked and where to render the template ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, best thing is to encapsulate into templates, and use reactive vars (meteor add reactive-var )

then code wise

```
Template.articles.helpers({
    articleSet() {
      return [
        {
          name: "Article 1",
          text: "blah blah blah"
        },
        {
          name: "Article 2",
          text: "waffle waffle waffle"
        }
      ]
    }
  })

  Template.article.onCreated(function(){
    this.displayDetails = new ReactiveVar(false);
  })
  Template.article.helpers({
    displayDetails() {
      return Template.instance().displayDetails.get();
    }
  })
  Template.article.events({
    "click .showDetails": function(event, template) {
      template.displayDetails.set(!template.displayDetails.get());
    }
  })
```

and html

```
<template name="articles">
  <div>
    {{#each articleSet}}
      {{> article}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="article">
  <div>{{name}}</div>
  {{#if displayDetails}}
    <div>{{text}}</div>
  {{/if}}
  <button class="showDetails">Show</button>
</template>
```

see [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/xbRy4TBpuBrX79oyW/Copy%20of%20Leaderboard)

Answer (score 1):

let your template name is `articles`,then it'd be something like this.And in your blaze each loop, you don't need to write `article.name`, it'd be just `name`

```
Template.articles.events({
   'click button' : function() {
        console.log(this.name); // it would print your button value,basically this refers to the article object which gets clicked
        // load your article here
   }
});
```

Comment: The reason I write articleSet and article.name, is because it is easier to read when there is a lot of code. I want that somebody that does not understand Meteor, can read the code without too much effort.